# Checking disk space for tmpfs Nagios

Tags: snmp, disk-space-utilization, nagios, centreon

Here is the result of df on my target computer
`~# df -h
Filesystem                                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vgsys-lvroot                       11G  5.4G  5.0G  52% /
udev                                           24G  4.0K   24G   1% /dev
tmpfs                                         4.0G  256K  4.0G   1% /tmp
tmpfs                                         4.8G  6.1M  4.7G   1% /run
none                                          5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                                           24G     0   24G   0% /run/shm
/dev/mapper/vgsys-lvopt                        30G   25G  4.8G  84% /opt
/dev/sda1                                     226M   71M  144M  34% /boot`

And the result of the polling via snmp from my nagios poller:

```
 # ./check_snmp_storage.pl -H 172.x.x.x -v 1 -C public -m tmpfs -w 80 -c 90
Filter : tmpfs
OID : 1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.8, Desc : Shared memory
OID : 1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.35, Desc : /opt
OID : 1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.6, Desc : Memory buffers
OID : 1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.1, Desc : Physical memory
OID : 1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.33, Desc : /dev
OID : 1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.32, Desc : /sys/fs/fuse/connections
OID : 1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.36, Desc : /boot
OID : 1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.7, Desc : Cached memory
OID : 1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.3, Desc : Virtual memory
OID : 1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.10, Desc : Swap space
OID : 1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3.31, Desc : /
storages selected : 0
Unknown storage : tmpfs : ERROR
```

As you can see, the tmpfs filesystems are not showed in SNMP. (but I tried without hope (neither success) "-m tmp", "-m /tmp")

Is it possible ?

Someone know a plugin to monitor a tmpfs filesystem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the fault of `check_snmp_storage.pl`. Oddly, the hrStorage branch [includes types for "RamDisk" (hrStorageTypes 8)](http://www.simpleweb.org/ietf/mibs/modules/IETF/txt/HOST-RESOURCES-TYPES), but an snmpwalk confirms what you are seeing: it ignores tmpfs mounts.

[According to the usage documentation](http://nagios.manubulon.com/snmp_storage.html), you can explicitly (try to) force the script to check RamDisk storage using `-q RamDisk`.

You can use the standard `check_disk` plugin with the NRPE agent to check tmpfs mounts, though.

Comment: Keith,
`./check_snmp_storage.pl -C public -H 172.x.x.x -w 1 -c 2 -v -q RamDisk -m *`
doesn't output the RamDisk. If you tried with snmpwalk, I guess it isn't possible without agent.
I'll try with NRPE. Thanks